# How to mark exported function as used somewhere in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, jsdoc

I have something like that:

- modules with exported functions
- a resolver function that would `require` via an alias like `module-name/function-name`
- a json file in other repo that maps pages and functions to be called to load page data via these async functions.

The `module-name` is just a directory name from which the `index.js` would be `require` -ed.

resolver function works like that:

```js
export function resolveModuleFunction(moduleName, functionName) {
    if (moduleName.indexOf('~/modules') === 0) {
        moduleName = moduleName.replace('~/','../');
    } else if (moduleName.indexOf('~modules/') === 0) {
        moduleName = moduleName.replace('~modules/','../modules/');
    } else if (moduleName.indexOf('~/') === 0) {
        moduleName = moduleName.replace('~/','../');
    }
    return function(...params) {
        let moduleInstance = require(moduleName);
        if (moduleInstance.default) {
            moduleInstance = moduleInstance.default;
        }
        return moduleInstance[functionName].apply(moduleInstance, params);
    };
}
```

It works, and all I want to get for now is to explain to IDE that functions to be used via these dynamic references - e. g. with these aliases in other repos with markup, are "used somewhere else", and avoid these "exported function X of module Y is unused".

I don't want **right now** to re-factor that part of system to typescript file(s) that would register the pages in code.

I just looking for a way (with a JSDoc may be?) to mark an exported function to be used somewhere?

I thought about making some `exported-functions.md` file where these modules and their functions would be listed in a `JS` markdown blocks, both for documentation purposes and for  getting that effect of exported functions considered to be "used somewhere".

Is there other way to achieve it, with some keyword at per-function JSDoc?